# please explain following out put

Tags: php

Here, I have following code it getting output like 21,21. How 21 value comes in $a

```
 $a = '1';
 $b = &$a;
 $b = "2$b";
 echo $a.", ".$b;
```

Output

```
 21,21
```

Comment: after ` $b = &$a;` a and b point to the same value

Comment: reference  document

Comment: Reference `php.net`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask an explanation about code that's working as intended. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing by reference $a to $b with the & symbol. That means if you change the value of $b you are changing $a too.

In other words $b has the memory address of $a

Answer (score 0):

`$b = &$a;`

This is the culprit. If you just want $b to be a copy of $a, change the statement to

`$b = $a;`

By using the `&`, you are not making a copy, instead you are saying that both variables should point at the same memory location ('pass by reference' as opposed to 'pass by value'). Therefore if you store a different value at the memory location using one variable, say `$b`, the other variable, `$a`, is automatically updated as well.